# RShiny - displaying different numbers of output graphs depending on input category

Tags: r, shiny

I am looking to display different numbers of graphs, depending on the input category selected in the drop down menu. I cant see a way to do this, as R Shiny only seems to allow one output. I have outlined a very simple example below. I realise that histograms are unncessary and probably could be displayed in one graph; however the actual example I am doing is more complicated and needs multiple graphs.

```
gender <- c("male","male","female","female","male","male","male")
sports <-c("running","swimming","basketball","fishing","karate","hockey","gymnastics")
regularplayer <-c(.2,.4,.3,.5,.1,.1,.1)
casualplayer <-c(.2,.3,.6,.2,.2,.2,.2)
nonplayer <-c(.6,.3,.1,.3,.7,.7,.7)

sports <-as.data.frame(cbind(gender,sports,regularplayer,casualplayer,nonplayer))

ui <- fluidPage(

      selectInput("gender","Select Gender",c("Male","Female"))
    )



server <-function(input, output) {

  output$gender <- renderPlot({   

    if (input$gender == "Male") {

    # Need to create 5 histograms, one for each sport by% played
    }
    else if (input$gender == "Female") {

      # Need to create 2 histograms, one for each sport by% played
    }

      #return graphs as single output, either 5 or 2 depending on gender selected

  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible way to go:

global.R 
To hold the data. Put it in the same folder as ui.R and server.R
don't worry about the waring message of the melt function, it is because not all sports are present in the female case.

```
    library(reshape2)
    gender <- c("male","male","female","female","male","male","male")
    sports <-c("running","swimming","basketball","fishing","karate","hockey","gymnastics")
    regularplayer <-c(.2,.4,.3,.5,.1,.1,.1)
    casualplayer <-c(.2,.3,.6,.2,.2,.2,.2)
    nonplayer <-c(.6,.3,.1,.3,.7,.7,.7)

    sports <-as.data.frame(cbind(gender,sports,regularplayer,casualplayer,nonplayer))
    sports_melted <- melt(sports, id.vars = c("gender", "sports"), variable.name = "player_type", value.name = "player_percent")
```

ui.R

```
    library(shiny)


    shinyUI(fluidPage(


      titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),


      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
                selectInput("gender","Select Gender",c("Male","Female"))
        ),


        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("gender")
        )
      )
    ))
```

server.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)

    # Define server logic required to draw a histogram
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

            output$gender <- renderPlot({   

                    if (input$gender == "Male") {
                            male_data <- filter(sports_melted, gender == "male")
                            gg <- ggplot(male_data, aes(x=player_type, y = player_percent))
                            gg <- gg + geom_bar(stat = "identity") 
                            gg <- gg + facet_grid(.~sports)
                            # Need to create 5 histograms, one for each sport by% played
                    }
                    else if (input$gender == "Female") {
                            female_data <- filter(sports_melted, gender == "female")
                            gg <- ggplot(female_data, aes(x=player_type, y = player_percent))
                            gg <- gg + geom_bar(stat = "identity") 
                            gg <- gg + facet_grid(.~sports)
                    }

                    gg

            })

    })
```

Comment: Thanks so much. THis is exactly what I need!